# How remove "All" in menu responsive Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, mobile-menu

[image: Menu mobile]

On file:

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/menu.js
```

I modify the line 463:

```
this.categoryLink = $('<a>')
.attr('href', categoryUrl)
.text($.mage.__('All %1').replace('%1', category));
```

By :

```
this.categoryLink = $('<a>')
.attr('href', categoryUrl)
.text(category);
```

And I launched :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

But that doesn't change anything, what do you recommend ?

Comment: check this link -- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156586/magento-2-3rd-level-menu-items-collapsed-on-mobile-devices

Comment: Finally I added this CSS code to hide the line : .all-category {display: none}